# print out HelloWorld in C in ECLIPSE

Tags: c++, console, mingw, eclipse-cdt, stdio

after i died severel deaths i want to ask you if you can give me a tipp:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwDn3.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

After I built it, the exe appears in my workspace. Then after i wanted to run this exe disappears ...

I have no idea... maybe i need to setup eclipse again?
should i reinstall mingw ?

I tried it now with cmd:

[image]

i also wanted to try it some seconds later... but i think the exe jsut disappeared xD
[image]

Comment: Does `fuuu.exe` work if you start it in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: thank you for your answer^^ i tried it now in cmd.exe... i just went to the directory and typed in fuuu.exe... but the permission was denied

Comment: Not sure why this would be the case. I don't think reinstalling `mingw` or `eclipse` would fix that. You should investigate the permission problem in your OS.

Comment: i recently "reinstalled" eclipse .. but it made no difference... i will try to reinstall mingw :D  lol but how to reinstall mingw.. i need to check .. a of course. just delete the folder :D aaah moment i didnt delete the old eclipse.. i installed a new eclipse parallel and also started the old isntalled version again xD

Comment: NO ... still doesnt work.. same effect.. after reinstalling mingw and starting a new installed eclipse

Comment: I did not expect it to work. I said I don't think reinstalling mingw or eclipse would fix that.

Comment: I think you need to fix the permissions problem in your OS. Check the permissions of the folder that contains your executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203528/discussion-between-user3786459-and-drescherjm).